# Given $7$. degree polynomial $p(x)$, prove that all roots of $x^{10}-10x^9+39x^8=p(x)$ are in $(-\frac{5}{2},\frac{9}{2})$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, quadratics, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Suppose $p(x)$ is a polynomial of the degree at most $7$ and assume that the following equation has $10$ real roots
> $$x^{10}-10x^9+39x^8=p(x)$$
> Prove that all roots are in $(-\frac{5}{2},\frac{9}{2})$.

My try: If $x_0,x_1,...,x_9$ are all roots then by Vieta's formula's we have: $$\sum_{i=0}^9x_i = 10$$ and  $$\sum_{0\le i<j\le 9}x_ix_j = 39$$
Then $$\sum_{i=0}^9x_i^2 = 10^2- 2\cdot 39 = 22$$
I suppose we may assume there is a root not in  $(-\frac{5}{2},\frac{9}{2})$, say $x_0$. But what now?

Comment: Why don't you just factor out $x^8$ from your polynomial (0 is a root of multiplicity 8) and find the other 2 roots using the quadratic formula?

Comment: @Riley Because then the quadratic polynomial $x^2-10x+39$ does not even have real roots, so contradiction?

Comment: If it doesn't have 10 real roots, then you were wrong in assuming that it had 10 real roots.

Comment: $p(x)$ is given polynomial of the degree at most 7

Comment: What is unclear?

Comment: Your $p(x)=x^{10}...$ has degree $10$.

Comment: $$x=0$$ is one real solution of multiplicity $8$

Comment: @DietrichBurde read the problem.

Comment: So the equation is like $x^{10}-10x^9+39x^8= ax^7+bx^6+...+c$

Comment: I don't know but for me `at most 7` means that $p$ can have any degree from $0$ to $7$, so if we take $p(x) = 0$ we get a contradiction since then all the roots all roots are complex expect $0$.

Comment: But this means that you can't take $p(x)=0$ since then the equation doesnt have 10 real roots!

Comment: @JohnWatson I don't think I am fully convinced but I can't find a counter example easily.

Comment: @123 yes you are right, p can have the degree from 0 to 7, but the equation must have 10 real roots, so you can' t take just any $p(x)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For all $i$ by C-S we obtain:

$$22-x_i^2=\frac{1}{9}\sum_{k\neq i}1^2\sum_{k\neq i}x_k^2\geq\frac{1}{9}\left(\sum_{k\neq i}x_k\right)^2=\frac{1}{9}(10-x_i)^2,$$ which gives 
$$5x_i^2-10x_i-49\leq0,$$ which implies 
$$x_i\in\left(-2.5,4.5\right).$$
Done!

Comment: How did you get this formulas. What was the motivation?

Comment: @John Watson I want to get inequality of one variables $x_i$ and I got it.

Comment: @John Watson You are welcome!

Comment: @John Watson Why did you do it? I think it's not fair.

Comment: @John Watson Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is just rewriting Michael's solution. So if we mark 
$$a= \sum_{i=1}^9x_i = 10-x_0$$
and 
$$b= \sum_{i=1}^9x_i^2 = 22-x_0^2$$
By Cauchy inequality we know that $$ 9b\geq a^2$$
so we get $$9(22-x_0^2) \geq (10-x_0)^2$$ 
and know we have $$5x_0^2 -10x_0 -49 \leq 0$$
and thus the solution. :)